# Odoo13-CE: Module: crm.lead: What inherit_id do I need to inherit the following view (see the screenshot)?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

Module: crm.lead: What inherit_id do I need to inherit the following view (see the screenshot)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.quick_create_opportunity_form"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `inherit_id` it's belong to [Inheritance fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/views.html#inheritance-fields): the current view’s parent view, unset by default. Specify the parent using the ref attribute:

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.quick_create_opportunity_form"/>
```

Then you can positioned on the parent xml view to modificated using `xpath` or `field`.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.